# How can I simulate gravity or jump for a div using only html, css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a plataform game similar to Mario Bros I already have the left and right movement, but now I need to simulate a jump only using javascript, css and html i have this code [right now](https://codepen.io/erivaldo/pen/jmZVGG)

```
<div id="container">
<div id="roll"></div>
<div id="tube1" class="tube"></div>
<div id="tube2" class="tube"></div>
<div id="tube3" class="tube"></div>
<script>      
  var reqID, dir;    
  var left = 0;
  var top = 0;
  var player, tube, pw, ph, px, py, tw, th, tx, ty;     

  function detectCollisions() {
    //Access the current location and dimension of both objects
    for(let i = 0; i < tube.length; i++)
    {
      pw = player.offsetWidth;
      ph = player.offsetHeight;
      px = player.offsetLeft;
      py = player.offsetTop;
      tw = tube[i].offsetWidth;
      th = tube[i].offsetHeight;
      tx = tube[i].offsetLeft;
      ty = tube[i].offsetTop;
      console.log(tw);      
      //check to see if tube has intersected width player in any direction

      if((px+pw) > tx && px < (tx+tw) && (py+ph) > ty && py < (ty+th)) {
        //Do anything you want in the program when collision is detected
        console.log("collision detected with" + tube[i].id);
        this.player.style.left = (player.offsetLeft -= 3) + 'px';
        /*document.body.removeChild(tube[i]);*/

      }        
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(detectCollisions);
  }   

  function stopAnimation() {
    console.log('stop');
    /*window.cancelAnimationFrame(reqID);*/
    player.style.animation = "face-forward 0.9s steps(4) infinite";
  }

  function move(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode)
    //up
    if(e.keyCode == 38) {              
      player.style.top = (player.offsetTop -= 3) + 'px';
    } else if(e.keyCode == 39) { //right arrow                
      player.style.left = (player.offsetLeft += 3) + 'px';
      player.style.animation = "walk-right 0.9s steps(4) infinite";
    } else if(e.keyCode == 40) { //down arrow                
      player.style.top = (player.offsetTop += 3) + 'px';
    } else if(e.keyCode == 37) { //left arrow                
      player.style.left = (player.offsetLeft -= 3) + 'px';
      player.style.animation = "walk-left 0.9s steps(4) infinite";
    }

    /*reqID = window.requestAnimationFrame(startAnimation);*/
  }

  function createScenario() {
    var positionLeft = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        let iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.id = 'floor' + i;
        iDiv.className = 'floor';
        iDiv.style.left = positionLeft + 'px';
      iDiv.style.top = 170 + 'px';
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(iDiv);
        positionLeft += 35;     
    }

    /*let iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = "roll";
    iDiv.style.zIndex = "5";
    document.getElementByTagName('body').appendChild(iDiv);*/
  }

  /*Setting everything at the beggining*/
  var spriteSheet = new Image();
  spriteSheet.src = './resources/king_left_right.png';
  function docReady() {    
    /*player = document.createElement("div");
    player.id = "roll";
    player.style.backgroundPosition = "background-position: 200px -5px;"
    player.style.background = "url("+spriteSheet.src+")";
    document.body.appendChild(player);*/
    player = document.getElementById('roll');
    player.style.backgroundPosition = "background-position: 200px -5px;"
    player.style.background = "url("+spriteSheet.src+")";
    tube = document.getElementsByClassName("tube");
    detectCollisions();
        createScenario();
  }

  document.onkeydown = move;
  document.onkeyup = stopAnimation;
  window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    docReady();
  });
</script>
```

Could you give me an approch please, of course my character must jump and return to the ground or on the tube in the code.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Please review [ask]. This question appears to be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I made this site [Mindhive](http://mindhive.co.nz/) some time ago. If you click the hexagons they'll all drop but depending on how you click them they'll drop differently. You can fling them around with your mouse too.

I used [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) which is a javascript physics engine that should give you all the tools you need to get something built in Javascript, html etc with realistic gravity and movement.

Hope that helps a bit

Comment: It looks nice but Unfortunately i can't use librarys... :(

Comment: is there a reason you can't use libraries? Seems you might have to write a lot of code to get something realistic working.

Comment: ah unlucky. Still maybe having a look at how the library approaches it could give you some clues as to how to approach it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_bouncing.asp

May give you basic idea.